# How do I mock different value and ref.current.value on an Input component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-hooks

Good day to all:

I am trying to write jest test cases for the below component, but cannot figure out how to write a test for the line "if (value === valueRef.current.value)". How do I mock a value to be different from reference current value?

Thank you.

```
  const Input = ({
      setEnteredValueHandler
    }) => {
      const [value, setValue] = useState(defValue);
      const valueRef = useRef();
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
          if (value === valueRef.current.value) {
            setEnteredValueHandler(value);
          }
        }, 500);
        return () => {
          clearTimeout(timer);
        };
      }, [value]);
    
      return (
            <input
              value={value}
              ref={valueRef}
              onChange={e => setValue(e)}
            />
      );
    };
    
    
    export default Input;
```

Answer (score 0):

By now your component has logical error: `value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e)}`. It sets `Event` into `value`. I believe it should be `onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}`.

Next about component. By now the only way to get `value` and `valueRef.current.value` different is to change latter one programmatically. Any other interaction(keypress or input) will call `onChange` handle and set `value` equal to `valueRef.current.value`.

Also we need [mock timer](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks) to avoid waiting for real 500ms.

```
test('does not call callback if value has been changed programmatically during 500ms', () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    const setEnteredValueHandler = jest.fn();
    const { getByRole } = render(<Input setEnteredValueHandler={setEnteredValueHandler} />);
    const input = getByRole('textbox');
    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "aaa" } });
    input.value = "aa";
    expect(setEnteredValueHandler).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(502);
    expect(setEnteredValueHandler).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

It's for React-Testing-Library instead of Enzyme, but it should be easier to adapt.

And related test for case when value has not been changed programmatically so callback is called after 500ms.

```
test('calls callback if value has not been changed programmatically during 500ms', () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();
  const setEnteredValueHandler = jest.fn();
  const { getByRole } = render(<Input setEnteredValueHandler={setEnteredValueHandler} />);
  const input = getByRole('textbox');
  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "aaa" } });
  expect(setEnteredValueHandler).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(499);
  expect(setEnteredValueHandler).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(2);
  expect(setEnteredValueHandler).toHaveBeenCalledWith("aaa");
});
```